# Can I transfer iOS apps from expired developer account to another active one?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

My Developer account has been expired and I won't renew it, Can I transfer apps from this **expired** account to another **active** account

Comment: Logon using the expired account to see if that feature is still available.

Comment: You have to contact Apple. They will give you temporary access (usually 24 hours) to complete the transfers. This happened to me